# Compute probability of choose some elements of a sublist of a list.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

For different reasons, I need to compute some probability. Indeed, I want to compute the probability of being found in a list of length $26000$ in the first fifth slot, one of the elements of a sublist of length $40$.

Choose $5$ of the $40$ as the combinatory number. But I don't know how to integrate all the information to compute the probability.

Any help is welcome. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: "First fifth slot." Do you mean the first five slots?

Comment: So, you have a list $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{26000}$ and a random sub-list of size $40,$, and you want to know the probability the sub-list contains at least one of $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5?$

Comment: **Exactly** one of the elements or **at least** one of the elements ?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes! You are complete right, that's my question.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I computed how many possibilities of the 5-list are taken from the 40-list, and I added how many possible 40-sublist are from the 2600-list. But I don not got how to mix the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your confirmation of "at least" one,

There are $5$ "good" elements and $(26000 -5) = 25995$ "bad" ones

Then P(find at least one "good" element in first $5$ of a random sublist of $40$)

$= 1 - P$(find no "good" element in first $5$ of such a sublist )

$= 1 - \Large{\frac{\binom{25995}{5}}{\binom{26000}{5}}} \approx 9.61/10000$

---

### Alternative interpretation

One of $5$ "good" numbers are found **anywhere** in a random list of $40$

In similar vein, Pr $= 1 - \Large\frac{\binom{25995}{40}}{\binom{26000}{40}} \approx 0.00767$

Comment: Those binomial coefficients should have 40 on the bottom, right?

Comment: @Karl: You have *bought* $40$ lottery tickets, but you can get a prize only if  matching number(s) are there in the first $5$ serial numbers of your tickets !

Comment: So where does the 40 come in?

Comment: @Karl: You have bought $40$ tickets. However, I'll put the alternative interpretation also in the answer.

Comment: What I mean is, shouldn't the number 40 appear in your calculation somewhere? Certainly if we bought 26000 tickets the probability would be higher.

Comment: The first interpretation was that you **bought** $40$ tickets, but only the first five (according to serial number) counted